# MySQL left join on nearest value

Tags: mysql

I have this table with values thickness and speed.

[image]

I use this query to find the correct speed compared to the thickness.

```
SELECT
prf.id AS id,
prf.artikelcode AS artikelcode,
prf.omschrijving AS omschrijving,
prf.dikte AS dikte,
prf.gewicht_m AS gewicht_m,
prf.verfopp_m AS verfopp_m,
grp.prijs AS groep_prijs,
grp.prijs_eenheid AS groep_prijs_eenheid,
snelh.snelheid AS snelheid
FROM profielen AS prf
LEFT JOIN profiel_groep AS grp
ON grp.id = prf.profiel_groep_id
LEFT JOIN calculatie_snelheid AS snelh
ON snelh.dikte <= prf.dikte
ORDER BY prf.artikelcode ASC
```

Not all speeds are stored, I opted for `equal and smaller` but I am getting different values for the same thickness. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you JOIN a new table, everything else will be cloned for each successful join in the new table.  In this case, `ON snelh.dikte <= prf.dikte` is matching every price lower than it.

I would probably do this GROUP BY: (indents to help show where changes are)

```
SELECT prf.id              AS id,
       prf.artikelcode     AS artikelcode,
       prf.omschrijving    AS omschrijving,
       prf.dikte           AS dikte,
       prf.gewicht_m       AS gewicht_m,
       prf.verfopp_m       AS verfopp_m,
       grp.prijs           AS groep_prijs,
       grp.prijs_eenheid   AS groep_prijs_eenheid,
       MAX(snelh.snelheid) AS snelheid
FROM      profielen AS prf
LEFT JOIN profiel_groep AS grp
       ON grp.id = prf.profiel_groep_id
LEFT JOIN calculatie_snelheid AS snelh
       ON snelh.dikte <= prf.dikte
GROUP BY id, 
         artikelcode, 
         omschrijving, 
         prf.dikte, 
         gewicht_m, 
         verfopp_m, 
         groep_prijs_eenheid
ORDER BY prf.artikelcode ASC
```

The MAX() in the SELECT will get you just the largest value that matches, and the GROUP BY should clean out the extra rows.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a LEFT join to `calculatie_snelheid`, use a correlated subquery that returns the `snelheid` of the row with `dikte` that is the closest to `dikte` of `profielen`:

```
SELECT
  prf.id AS id,
  prf.artikelcode AS artikelcode,
  prf.omschrijving AS omschrijving,
  prf.dikte AS dikte,
  prf.gewicht_m AS gewicht_m,
  prf.verfopp_m AS verfopp_m,
  grp.prijs AS groep_prijs,
  grp.prijs_eenheid AS groep_prijs_eenheid,
  (
    SELECT snelh.snelheid 
    FROM calculatie_snelheid AS snelh
    WHERE snelh.dikte <= prf.dikte
    ORDER BY prf.dikte - snelh.dikte LIMIT 1 
  ) AS snelheid
FROM profielen AS prf LEFT JOIN profiel_groep AS grp
ON grp.id = prf.profiel_groep_id
ORDER BY prf.artikelcode ASC
```